# Append text at the beginning of a file without deleting the file

Tags: java

There are many posts about this but I couldn't find one working correctly For Example below code works but it deletes the first line.

I want to insert some text at the beginning of a file without deleting anything, just an insert. Is that possible?

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(new File("myFile.txt"), "rw");
f.seek(0);
f.write("Blah Blah This is first line".getBytes());
f.close();
```

I also tried [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html), still deletes the first 12 bytes

Comment: use the code you posted, but first read in the line and add that to the text you are inserting before writing it back to the file

Comment: @Hrqls tnx Coudl you briefly show it in an example as anwer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudocode is

```
String existing = Read whole content of file. 

String newcontent = "Blah Blah This is first line" + existing

f.write(newcontent);
```

Comment: Yup. File systems don't generally support inserting data in-between or at the beginning of the file. Appending to the end is supported though.